# Supporting dragging and panning in a scrollable div with Pointer Events

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, pointer-events

Consider the case of a draggable div in a scrollable region. When you touch inside the div, further finger movements should drag the div around the region. When you touch outside the div, further finger movements should pan the scrollable region.

I have a JSFiddle which illustrates this. With the mouse, I can drag the div around easily, but touch events don't seem to work as well.

Note: I'm using pointer events in the fiddle, so if you're using a browser that doesn't support them, it might seem like the fiddle is broken.

Does anyone know how to properly implement this interaction?

http://jsfiddle.net/mrmills/13t34jsv/

HTML:

```
<div id="scroll-outer">
  <div id="scroll-inner">
    <div id="handle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#scroll-outer { width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow: auto }
#scroll-inner { width: 2000px; height: 2000px }
#handle { width: 44px; height: 44px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) }
```

JS:

```
function pointerDown(ev) {
  scrollInner.addEventListener("pointermove", pointerMove);
  scrollInner.addEventListener("pointerup", pointerUp);

  dragStartX = ev.pageX; dragStartY = ev.pageY;
}

function pointerMove(ev) {
  handle.style.transform = "translate3d(" +
    (x + ev.pageX - dragStartX) + "px, " +
    (y + ev.pageY - dragStartY) + "px, 0)";
}

function pointerUp(ev) {
  scrollInner.removeEventListener("pointermove", pointerMove);
  scrollInner.removeEventListener("pointerup", pointerUp);

  x = x + ev.pageX - dragStartX;
  y = y + ev.pageY - dragStartY;
}

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var dragStartX = 0;
var dragStartY = 0;

var handle = document.getElementById("handle");
var scrollInner = document.getElementById("scroll-inner");
handle.addEventListener("pointerdown", pointerDown);
```

Comment: Convert the `pointermove` event listener to `mousedown` which is recognized by all browsers.  Then make it so that a `class` is added to the `div` on mousedown.  Then invoke a `while` statement of which the condition will be while the mouse is down.  Lastly, when the `mouseup` event is triggered, remove the custom class and stop the `while` loop.  The gist is to create a specific condition for when the `div` is supposed to move, and abide by it.

Comment: I'm using the PEP polyfill to allow other browsers to use pointer events. It seemed overly-complex to add the polyfill to the question and demonstration pages, though.

Comment: For PEP to function you will need to use the HTML attributes `touch-action="none"` on the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fire pointer events with a touch-based input on an element, you need to set the CSS attribute `touch-action: none` (default is `auto`) on that element.

In your case setting `touch-action: none` on `div#handle` would make it draggable.

---

Addition: If you use [PEP](https://github.com/jquery/PEP), you will have to add the HTML data-attribute `touch-action="none"` to the element, e.g.:

```
...
<div id="handle" touch-action="none"></div>
...
```

Comment: Followed your exact instruction and I cannot get the `div` to drag within the fiddle that the original poster provided.

Comment: Which device are you using, if you don't mind me asking? There are only few touch-based devices with native pointer event support.

Comment: What using google chrome (desktop).  The div does not drag for me.

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't support pointer events yet in the main line. You'd have to test with Edge or something.